# android : get an singleTask activity from background to foreground

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an app using phonegap and mobile jquery.

There's a point in my app where it is running in the background and if an event triggered from js, I want to make my app to come in foreground.

How can I make my app come to foreground from background. I have a single activity with following attribute:

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenLayout"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask"        
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

what i tried to make my app in foreground is :

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext , MainActivity.class);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

And

```
mContext.startActivity(((Activity)mContext).getIntent());
```

(MainActivity is the only activity in my app ) but it is not working. I am using android 4.0.

Update : In android 2.3 its working fine but its not working in android 4.0

Comment: I have a similar issue. Has anyone found a solution to this ?

Comment: You can accept your own answer so is easier for other users to see if there's a good answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a effort I got a solution...
I implemented a broadcast listener. when i receive any event, i send a broadcast and in broadcast receiver i launch the app.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NotificationBroadcastReceiver.class);
        mContext.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

** Receiver** :

```
public final class NotificationBroadcastReceiver  extends BroadcastReceiver {
      @Override
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
         System.out.println("Broadcast recieved");
         context.startActivity(new Intent(context,A.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
      }
}
```